# Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app' in Aws Lambda using Chalice

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

I am having below lambda function which uses Chalice.

```
from chalice import Chalice
from chalicelib import lookup_helper
import os 

try:
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import unquote

app = Chalice(app_name='some_app')
@app.route('/some_route', methods=['GET'])
def some_func(arg):
    //some code
```

When I test this function I get below error

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
Tue Sep 22 11:59:10 UTC 2020 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'app'.
```

Can anyone please help me out here.
Python - 3.7

Update--

```
from chalice import Chalice
import os 

app = Chalice(app_name='some_app')
@app.route('/some_route', methods=['GET'])
def some_func(arg):
    return {}
```

Reduced the function to above. Still same error.

When I checked the pipeline (azure devops), I see below error in the logs, though the step passes as a whole.

```
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'build/lambda/requests'
```

requirement.txt

```
requests==2.22.0
```

Comment: 'azure devops' ? Are you running on AWS or Azure?

Comment: using azure devops to deploy on aws. I zeroed on the error.  This is coming when I am trying to call requests.get - AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Comment: share the code... we are talking now about a different problem..

Answer (score 1):

see https://chalice-workshop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/media-query/00-intro-chalice.html

> Add a new function hello_world decorated by app.lambda_function() that
> returns {"hello": "world"}. Your app.py file should now consist of the
> following lines:

```
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='workshop-intro')

@app.lambda_function()
def hello_world(event, context):
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

What is the name of you python file. Is it '**app.py**' ?

Comment: Yes. It's app.py

Comment: and if you reduce your code to the code in the example?

Comment: reduced it to minimum. Still same error. Updated the post